# Swift: Merge Sort Algorithm with alternate keys

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have an object with properties: Name, Relevance, Timestamp.

I want the objects in the array to be sorted interlaced by Most Relevant("Relevance") and Most Recent("Timestamp").

Such as: Relevant, Recent, Relevant, Recent, etc...

Now, I have a solution to sort based on a single key with Time Complexity of O(n log n).

Here's my solution in Swift:

```
func mergeSort(array: [Entity]) -> [Entity] {
    guard array.count > 1 else { return array }    // 1

    let middleIndex = array.count / 2              // 2

    let leftArray = mergeSort(Array(array[0..<middleIndex]))             // 3

    let rightArray = mergeSort(Array(array[middleIndex..<array.count]))  // 4

    return merge(leftPile: leftArray, rightPile: rightArray)             // 5
}


    func merge(leftPile leftPile: [Entity], rightPile: [Entity]) -> [Entity] {
    // 1
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0

    // 2
    var orderedPile = [Entity]()

    // 3
    while leftIndex < leftPile.count && rightIndex < rightPile.count {
            if leftPile[leftIndex].timestamp.isGreaterThanDate(rightPile[rightIndex].timestamp) {
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1
            } else if leftPile[leftIndex].timestamp.isLessThanDate(rightPile[rightIndex].timestamp) {
                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                rightIndex += 1
            }
            else{
                orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
                leftIndex += 1
                orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
                rightIndex += 1
            }
    }

    // 4
    while leftIndex < leftPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(leftPile[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
    }

    while rightIndex < rightPile.count {
        orderedPile.append(rightPile[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }

    return orderedPile
}
```

The code sorts the array for "Most Recent" perfectly and i can also change the key from "timestamp" to "relevance", to sort it for "Most Relevant".

But, i want interlaced sort as described above with shortest complexity. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sort by relevance.

Make a copy sorted by recentness.

Merge the copies in alternate order, keeping a dictionary of the ones in the merge and not adding them again.

The two sorts are `O(n log(n))` and the merge is `O(n)` for `O(n log(n))`.